# Where's my bounty points gone?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, expired-bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I had started [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208990/web-cam-type-video-camera-to-ipad2-streaming-over-wired-communication) question on stackoverflow but haven't got any useful answer. No answer has up votes that can qualifies for auto bounty assignment. What happened to my 50 points then? Doesn't it re-added to my reputation points?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What happened to my 50 points then? Doesn't it re-added to my reputation points?

The bounty points have gone

[image]

Bounty once started, is gone & isn't refunded [back to the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/133693).

Comment: This is interesting. I'll keep that in mind as I also wanted to start my first bounty recently.

Comment: Last time I try using bounty. EVER. Stupid rule. I got ZERO answers to my question.  Just threw away 100 points.

Comment: @WarreninToronto bounty doesn't guarantee an answer.

Comment: But the poof thing makes bounty a bigger risk.  A bounty that is awarded, fine, costs 100 points. Putting up a reward for something, and getting no phone calls even, and then the reward is gone anyways, that's how it works here. Which sucks.

Comment: @WarreninToronto As the [faq] says - `It will definitely get more attention, but we can't guarantee it will necessarily be acted upon.`. Sucks, but you can't demand something